# Android ImageView with space left and right

Tags: android, imageview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` with a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView`. My goal is to have the ImageView show my image in full height but overflowing width so you can scroll the image horizontally.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_indoor_tour"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000">

        <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scene"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#ffff00" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

It works in general but adds some spacing left and right that is part of the ImageView.

See screenshot.

[image]

Where does the spacing come from? How to remove this spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works fine in my case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_indoor_tour"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scene"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#ffff00" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I think the image itself has a left and right padding in it. It should work fine otherwise.

Comment: layout_width="match_parent" does not work alone but with android:adjustViewBounds="true" together it does. Android Studio says >This RelativeLayout should use android:layout_width="wrap_content"< but I ignore this for now since it works.

Comment: So it works right? At least I got it working in my side. Are you having the same problem with the code above?

Comment: Yes it works. But in combination with adjustViewBounds. Thx. Only Android Studio irritated me before because it complaints about using match_parent in RelativeLayout here but I ignore it now.

Comment: Great to know that it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute on the imageView:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to both the Relative Layout and the ImageView

Comment: scaleType="fitXY" scales the image but changes the ratio.
layout_width="match_parent" does not work alone but with android:adjustViewBounds="true" together it does.
Android Studio says >This RelativeLayout should use android:layout_width="wrap_content"< but I ignore this for now since it works.

Comment: so it still works, right? since it was modifying your code to include the attributes 